# Lengendre symbol calculation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to calculate the lengendre symbol of (3/383) without using the Quadratic Reciprocity Law, and with not much success.
I've thought about checking if 2^191 is congroent to 1 modulo 383 but it seems too complicated.
I'd be grateful if some could point me to the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a three, there is a two...what is it at the end? Please do edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to compute
$$
\left( \frac{2}{383} \right)
$$
you're after, $p = 383$ is a prime, so you calculate indeed
$$
2^{(p-1)/2} = 2^{191} \pmod{p},
$$
and you get $1$, so $2$ is a square modulo $p$.

If you have to do the calculation by hand, use the method of [repeated squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer,  is there any method of performing this calculation without using a calculator , or in other words -"by hands" ? Thanks

Comment: @itamar As I said, I would go for repeated squaring. At least that's what I require my students to do ;-) but they are allowed to use a calculator.

Comment: I've edited the post - it's (2/383) altough it doesn't really make difference about the method of claculation

Comment: @itamar, there's still a $3$ around.